# Docker-machine create failing at ssh command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, docker-machine

I am trying to create an ec2 spot instance using docker-machine. I tried to debug my command and found that it is failing at ssh.
I used ssh-keygen to create my key pair, and i have uploaded the key-pair to aws.
I am able to connect to the instance using putty. Please help me solving this error!

Also i am running the docker-machine command from an ec2 instance.

docker-machine version:

```
docker-machine version 0.13.0, build 9ba6da9
```

Command:

```
docker-machine --debug create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key xxxxxxxxx --amazonec2-secret-key xxxxxxxxx --amazonec2-ssh-user ubuntu --amazonec2-region us-east-1 --amazonec2-instance-type t2.large --amazonec2-ami ami-xxxxx--amazonec2-vpc-id vpc-xxxxx--amazonec2-subnet-id subnet-xxxx--amazonec2-zone a --amazonec2-root-size 32 --amazonec2-keypair-name id_rsa --amazonec2-ssh-keypath $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa --amazonec2-request-spot-instance --amazonec2-security-group dev --amazonec2-private-address-only --amazonec2-spot-price x.xx dev4
```

Error:

```
Using SSH client type: external
Using SSH private key: /home/centos/.docker/machine/machines/dev4/id_rsa (-rw-------)
&{[-F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none ubuntu@xx.xxx.x.xx -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /home/centos/.docker/machine/machines/dev4/id_rsa -p 22] /usr/bin/ssh <nil>}
About to run SSH command:
exit 0
SSH cmd err, output: exit status 255:
Error getting ssh command 'exit 0' : ssh command error:
command : exit 0
err     : exit status 255
output  :
```

docker-machine inspect dev4

```
{
    "ConfigVersion": 3,
    "Driver": {
        "IPAddress": "xx.xxx.xx.xx",
        "MachineName": "dev4",
        "SSHUser": "ubuntu",
        "SSHPort": 22,
        "SSHKeyPath": "/home/centos/.docker/machine/machines/dev4/id_rsa",
        "StorePath": "/home/centos/.docker/machine",
        "SwarmMaster": false,
        "SwarmHost": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376",
        "SwarmDiscovery": "",
        "Id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "AccessKey": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "SecretKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "SessionToken": "",
        "Region": "us-east-1",
        "AMI": "ami-xxxx",
        "SSHKeyID": 0,
        "ExistingKey": true,
        "KeyName": "id_rsa",
        "InstanceId": "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "InstanceType": "t2.large",
        "PrivateIPAddress": "xx.xxx.xx.xx",
        "SecurityGroupId": "",
        "SecurityGroupIds": [
            "sg-xxxxxx"
        ],
        "SecurityGroupName": "",
        "SecurityGroupNames": [
            "dev"
        ],
        "OpenPorts": null,
        "Tags": "",
        "ReservationId": "",
        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
        "RootSize": 32,
        "VolumeType": "gp2",
        "IamInstanceProfile": "",
        "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxx",
        "SubnetId": "subnet-xxxxx",
        "Zone": "a",
        "RequestSpotInstance": true,
        "SpotPrice": "x.xx",
        "BlockDurationMinutes": 0,
        "PrivateIPOnly": true,
        "UsePrivateIP": false,
        "UseEbsOptimizedInstance": false,
        "Monitoring": false,
        "SSHPrivateKeyPath": "/home/centos/.ssh/id_rsa",
        "RetryCount": 5,
        "Endpoint": "",
        "DisableSSL": false,
        "UserDataFile": ""
    },
    "DriverName": "amazonec2",
    "HostOptions": {
        "Driver": "",
        "Memory": 0,
        "Disk": 0,
        "EngineOptions": {
            "ArbitraryFlags": [],
            "Dns": null,
            "GraphDir": "",
            "Env": [],
            "Ipv6": false,
            "InsecureRegistry": [],
            "Labels": [],
            "LogLevel": "",
            "StorageDriver": "",
            "SelinuxEnabled": false,
            "TlsVerify": true,
            "RegistryMirror": [],
            "InstallURL": "https://get.docker.com"
        },
        "SwarmOptions": {
            "IsSwarm": false,
            "Address": "",
            "Discovery": "",
            "Agent": false,
            "Master": false,
            "Host": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376",
            "Image": "swarm:latest",
            "Strategy": "spread",
            "Heartbeat": 0,
            "Overcommit": 0,
            "ArbitraryFlags": [],
            "ArbitraryJoinFlags": [],
            "Env": null,
            "IsExperimental": false
        },
        "AuthOptions": {
            "CertDir": "/home/centos/.docker/machine/certs",
            "CaCertPath": "/home/centos/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem",
            "CaPrivateKeyPath": "/home/centos/.docker/machine/certs/ca-key.pem",
            "CaCertRemotePath": "",
            "ServerCertPath": "/home/centos/.docker/machine/machines/dev4/server.pem",
            "ServerKeyPath": "/home/centos/.docker/machine/machines/dev4/server-key.pem",
            "ClientKeyPath": "/home/centos/.docker/machine/certs/key.pem",
            "ServerCertRemotePath": "",
            "ServerKeyRemotePath": "",
            "ClientCertPath": "/home/centos/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem",
            "ServerCertSANs": [],
            "StorePath": "/home/centos/.docker/machine/machines/dev4"
        }
    },
    "Name": "dev4"
}
```

Comment: You use "centos" as "amazonec2-ssh-user" but ssh connection is made using "ubuntu". Might be an issue. Try to check the AMI you are using to be sure what is the default user.

Comment: yes i did change it, still the same error

Comment: I see you use "debug". It is surprisingly not very verbose. Maybe you can try "--native-ssh", see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, was able to solve the error, i created a security group manually with inbound rule for port ssh open to the ec2instance i am running, and added it to the instance , It worked like a charm :)